# string with numbers change type to long int

Tags: c++, string, types, long-integer, strtol

I am writing in C++ and I have a string. I want to check if this string is only numbers and If it is I want to change the type to long int.

```
                       stringT = "12836564128606764591"; 
                       bool temp = false;
                       for(char& ch : stringT) 
                       {
                        if(!isdigit(ch)) 
                          { 
                            temp=true;
                            break;
                          }
                       }
                       if(temp != true)
                       {
                        itm = new Item_int((long long) strtoll(stringT.c_str(), NULL, 0));
                        std::cout << " itm:" << *itm << std::endl;


                       }
```

but the result of print is: 9223372036854775807

Comment: What exactly `Item_int` is?

Comment: please read about [mcve]. Given the code you show here nobody will be able to tell you exactly why you get that output. If it is not relevant you could just remove that `Item_int` from the example

Answer (score 0):

First iterate over a string to find any non-numeric characters

```
bool is_number(const std::string& s)
    {
        std::string::const_iterator it = s.begin();
        while (it != s.end() && std::isdigit(*it)) ++it;
        return !s.empty() && it == s.end();
    }
```

Than convert string to int if is_number is succesful

```
long int number = 0;
if (is_number(stringT))
{
  number = std::stol(stringT);
}
```

Comment: He _is_ already  iterating over the string fo find if there are non-digit characters.

Comment: `number = Long.parseLong(stringT);` Are you sure this is C++?

Answer (score 0):

The number `12836564128606764591` is larger than what can fit into a `long long`.

The maximum a `long long` can hold is `9223372036854775807` (assuming `long long` is 64 bits.